# how to convert this code substr in php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, javascript-objects

how to convert this code substr in php to javascript?
this code run in php, but run in java script cannot

PHP

```
<?php
    $header='XII-40';
    $next=1022;
    $len=6;
    $id = $header.substr("000000000$next", -$len);
print   $id;
```

https://www.tehplayground.com/Fa2f6Jk0bP4UaLLz

```js
const str = 'XII-14';
const next=123
const text1='00000000001'+next
const len =6
console.log(text1.substr(next, len));
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: `.` in PHP is the concat operator. `+` is concat in JS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
const str = 'XII-14';
const next = 123;
const text1 = '00000000001' + next;
const len = 6;
console.log(str + text1.substr(-len));
```

It returns:

```
XII-14001123
```